# Nothing displayed using a Timelion syntax query

Tags: java, kibana, dashboard, timelion

Although I have a data in the **heap_committed**  field, when I'm trying to define this field values in the y-axe nothing had been displayed !!
My query :

```
.es(index=httpbeat-2018.09.23, timefield=@timestamp,metric=max:response.jsonBody.heap_committed).label("Heap committed")
```

Result :

[image: Query result]

Heap_committed data :

[image: Data in kibana]

Is there any issue with my query?

Comment: what's your time range? (on the up right corner of page) check whether it's Last 15min and change it to proper time range

Comment: @Amirmasudzarebidaki thanks  for  your reply, I  found  a solution to this  problem, in fact, the nested  columns  are not  supported  by kibana, And  the  fields  that i'm trying  to display are  nested